# How to use two nested web components Angular?

Tags: angular

I have two web components js files included on the page:

```
<script src="preview.js"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>

<app-preview data="data"></app-preview>
```

Inside `<app-preview>` I want to use `<app-map>` web component for that in `onInit()` of `<app-preview>` I create the container:

```
 this._map = this.document.createElement('app-map') as HTMLMapElement;
```

And append it into template using `@ViewChild`.

As result I got the only one web component on the page with inside inner web component:

```
<body>
   <app-preview data="data"></app-preview>
</body>
```

Problem is that the inner component is rendered only by hover any events are fired when user move the mouse outside the place where event was fired.

How to fix it and how to properly to use nested web components Angular?

**One important remark:**

If to use web components separataly like this:

```
<app-preview data="data"></app-preview>
<app-map></app-map>
```

There is not problem with rendering. It works.

The `app-map` template is:

```
<div
  toastContainer
  [style.width]="width"
  [style.height]="width"
  style="position: relative"
  id="{{ target }}"
  #map
></div>

<ng-container *ngIf="maploaded$ | async">
   MORE COMPONENTS
</ng-container>
```

So, when user hover over `#map` the events works. When user clicks, hovers etc inside `MORE COMPONENTS` the Angular does not render.

Comment: Seems you have to trigger `ChangeDetection` on any custom event. Do it manually.

Comment: Do you mean trigger detection from inside `app-map`? I have tried instantly  when I create a `app-map`  container inside `app-preview`. It does not work for me

Comment: I think problem in ngZone or in current focus